# find and replace html( not only text ) in ckeditor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ckeditor

I am using CKEDITOR 4 in my application.

Here I have a certain type of tag, let's say 'TagX'.

I need to add an 'id' attribute to only those TagX tags which doesn't have an id.

I have trued using:

```
content = EditorInstance.getData();
var pattRegex = /<(tagx)(?![^<>]*\bid=).*?<\/\1>/gi;
var arrTagsX = content.match(pattRegex);
for (i = 0; i < arrTagsX.length; i++) {
    content = content.replace("<tagx", <tagx id=\"id_" + i + "\"");
}
EditorInstance.setData(content);
```

Its working fine, but the content size is very large so I want to avoid `setData();`.

I want something to find the html (not only text) and replace the html with the html+id.

Comment: Please check my answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not using the `$('tagx')` and then use `$(this)` to do your staff later while displaying ?

So let's give the job to jquery with something like the following

```
var i=0;
$('tagx').each(function(){
   i++;
   $(this).attr('id','id_'+i);
});
```

**Edit regarding your other comment**

Let's test if `:not([id])`

```
var i=0;
$('tagx:not([id])').each(function(){
       i++;
       $(this).attr('id','id_'+i);
});
```

Comment: ya true... but i think it'll loop through all tagx (which have id and which doesn't have id). and **i don't want to loop through all those tagx which already have id attribute**.

Comment: ya Valky u r right... **but i think i've not explained my point properly...** let say i've **100** numbers of 'tagx' and only the **last (100th) one does not have the id**. so as per the above code i need to loop though 100 times to fix the id... **but i really don't want to loop for 100 times here** only one loop. that is the main issue here..

Comment: ya thanks Valky.. i was searching something like this only.let me try.

Answer (score 1):

finally i've updated my code as per bellow and its fulfill my requirement...

```
rootElement = EditorInstance.document.getElementsByTag("rootEle").getItem(0);
var tagxEle = rootElement.$.getElementsByTagName('tagx');
var i=0;
 $(tagxEle).not('[id]').each(function(){
    i++;                                        
    $(this).attr('id','tagx_'+i);
 });
```

thnx Valky for your answer...